# How can i make a custom widget so that form.is_valid() returns true, instead of manytomany relation <select> input?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, widget

models.py:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s,%s' % (self.title,self.content)


class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post


class PostModelFormNormalUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = { 'tag' : TextInput() }
        exclude = ('user', 'created', 'modified')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostModelFormNormalUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)      
        self.fields['tag'].help_text = None
```

views.py:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostModelFormNormalUser(request.POST)
        print form
        print form.errors           
        tagstring = form.data['tag']
        splitedtag = tagstring.split()

        if form.is_valid():
            temp = form.save(commit=False)
            temp.user_id = user.id
            temp.save()

            l = len(splitedtag)         
            for i in range(l):
                obj = Tag(name=splitedtag[i])
                obj.save()
                post.tag_set.add(obj)

            post = Post.objects.get(id=temp.id)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/viewpost/' + str(post.id))
    else:
        form = PostModelFormNormalUser()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('addpost.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here `form.is_valid()` is always false because it gets the tag as string from form. But it expects list as form.data['tag'] input. Can anyone tell me how can i fix it?

How can i write a custom widget to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom widget (you still want a TextInput), you want a custom *Field*. To do this, you should subclass `django.forms.Field`. Unfortunately the documentation is scant on this topic:

> If the built-in Field classes don’t meet your needs, you can easily create custom Field classes. To do this, just create a subclass of django.forms.Field. Its only requirements are that it implement a clean() method and that its init() method accept the core arguments mentioned above (required, label, initial, widget, help_text).

I found [this blog post](http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail) that covers both custom widgets and fields in more depth. The author disagrees with the documentation I quoted above - it's worth reading over.

For your specific situation, you would do something like this (untested):

```
class MyTagField(forms.Field):
    default_error_messages = {
        'some_error': _(u'This is a message re: the somr_error!'),
    }

    def to_python(self, value):
        # put code here to coerce 'value' (raw data from your TextInput)
        # into the form your code will want (a list of Tag objects, perhaps)

    def validate(self, value):
        if <not valid for some reason>:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['some_error'])
```

Then in your ModelForm:

```
class PostModelFormNormalUser(forms.ModelForm):
    tag = MyTagField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', 'created', 'modified')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostModelFormNormalUser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)      
        self.fields['tag'].help_text = None
```

Comment: Ok, `forms.Field` can solve it. Can you post the example with widget to solve the problem? And what is `if <not valid for some reason>:` , how to check this here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "example with widget", can you elaborate? As for the `<not valid for some reason>` part: that's up to you. The `validate()` method allows you to define situations where the input is not acceptable - for instance if this were an email input field, you could check that the input looks like an email address or something. As for your case, you will have to come up with criteria for validating the input (maybe there are some illegal characters or something).

Comment: I don't think using a custom widget is the right way to go about this - I'm not sure what that example would look like. Sorry! Maybe someone  else knows how to do it that way.

Comment: Actually this is the proble, can you give any clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323060/how-can-i-save-manytomany-field-in-django